# R repetitive math equation over vector

Tags: r, time-series

I have a vector looks like this:

```
> y
 [1] 6.7 5.3 3.3 6.7 3.3 4.7 4.7 6.7 3.3 6.7
```

And I was trying to calculate the estimated auto-covariance when the time shift `h = 3` using the formula below:

[image]

This is what I have done and I am wondering is there an easy way to do it than hard coding:

```
> 1/10 * (
+     (y[4] - mean(y))*(y[1] - mean(y)) + 
+     (y[5] - mean(y))*(y[2] - mean(y)) + 
+     (y[6] - mean(y))*(y[3] - mean(y)) + 
+     (y[7] - mean(y))*(y[4] - mean(y)) + 
+     (y[8] - mean(y))*(y[5] - mean(y)) + 
+     (y[9] - mean(y))*(y[6] - mean(y)) + 
+     (y[10] - mean(y))*(y[7] - mean(y))
+ )
[1] -0.04848
```

Comment: I'd make a for loop to be as general as possible.  And I'd calculate the mean outside the loop so as to do that calculation once rather than over and over, as you did in your unrolled solution.

Comment: @duffymo yes, for loop is absolutely the low hanging fruit to have a general solution.. but curious if there is some handy function to calculate those crazy math equations..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your own function like this:

```
my.cov <- function(y,h){
  y.bar <- mean(y)
  T <- length(y)
  (1/T) * sum((y[(h+1):T] - y.bar) * (y[1:(T-h)] -y.bar))
}
#Checking the function
> y <- c(6.7, 5.3, 3.3, 6.7, 3.3, 4.7, 4.7, 6.7, 3.3, 6.7)
> my.cov(y, h=3)
[1] -0.04848
```

Note that no `for` loop is involved since `*` is a vectorized operator.

Comment: I notice that fro yours and flodel's answers. You guys skipped the return function and it will automatically return.. I don't know if this a traditional R syntax or just a trick everyone use.

Comment: @B.Mr.W. straight from the manual: `If the end of a function is reached without calling return, the value of the last evaluated expression is returned.`

Answer (score 3):

I'd do this vectorized instead of using a loop. Faster and a bit cleaner:

```
> y <- c(6.7,5.3,3.3,6.7,3.3,4.7,4.7,6.7,3.3,6.7)
> t <- 1:7
> (1/10)*sum((y[t+3]-mean(y))*(y[t]-mean(y)))
[1] -0.04848
```

And it is trivial to turn this into a function...

```
foo <- function(x,lag) {
    n <- length(x)
    i <- 1:(n-lag)
    (1/n) * sum( (y[ i + lag ] - mean(y) ) *( y[ i ] - mean(y) ) )
    }

foo( y , 3 )
# [1] -0.04848
```

Comment: VERY nice.  +1 from me.

Comment: ...with a hardcoded `10`, `7`, the use of `t` (the function name for `transpose`), I disagree.

Comment: The forumla he posted was hardcoded to be 10 and 7... but the t I agree with.

Comment: @David it's not obvious from the way the question is written, but 10 is the length of the vector (which I assume will vary) and I assume that `h`, the shift, is also variable (your `t`).

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I didn't spend much time thinking about it, just wanted to get a vectorized solution out before I had to run and the OP went with the for loop approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a functional and vectorized approach:

```
autocov <- function(x, lag = 3)
  sum((tail(x, -lag) - mean(x)) *
      (head(x, -lag) - mean(x))) / length(x)

x <- c(6.7, 5.3, 3.3, 6.7, 3.3, 4.7, 4.7, 6.7, 3.3, 6.7)
autocov(x)
# [1] -0.04848
autocov(c(1:3, 1:3))
# [1] 0.33333333
```

This last example is to show you how I suspect your formula for the autocovariance is wrong. I would have thought:

```
autocov <- function(x, lag = 3) cov(tail(x, -lag), tail(x, -lag))

autocov(c(1:3, 1:3))
# [1] 1
```

(i.e., each signal should have its own mean and the scaling should be 1/7 using your example.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the autocovariance function `acf` in the `stats` package?

BTW: When you are dealing with time series, I suggest to use a time series object rather than a plain vector. I prefer the package `zoo`.

```
library(zoo)
test_zoo=zoo(c(6.7,5.3,3.3,6.7,3.3,4.7,4.7,6.7,3.3,6.7),1:10)
acf(test_zoo,type="covariance",lag.max=3,plot=FALSE)[3]

#Autocovariances of series ‘test_zoo’, by lag
#      3 
#-0.0485
```

Comment: I am actually using zoo package and it is good. However, I was just diving into the math behind it.. Thanks though.